# Is there a MAKELONGLONG function?

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to combine two 32-bit values to create a 64-bit value. I'm looking for something analogous to [`MAKEWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632663.aspx) and [`MAKELONG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632660.aspx). I can easily define my own macro or function, but if the API already provides one, I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: By "combine," do you mean "add" or "multiply"?

Comment: @mcandre: He means in the sense of MAKEWORD.

Comment: Andreas is right, @Mcandre. Like I said, "analogous to MAKEWORD and MAKELONG."

Comment: I know you are an expert Delphi programmer, so it would be very interesting see your Delphi implementation, or hear what you have to say about my `asm` trick below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find any in the Windows API. However, I do know that you work mostly (or, at least, a lot) with Delphi, so here is a quick Delphi function:

```
function MAKELONGLONG(A, B: cardinal): UInt64; inline;
begin
  PCardinal(@result)^ := A;
  PCardinal(cardinal(@result) + sizeof(cardinal))^ := B;
end;
```

Even faster:

```
function MAKELONGLONG(A, B: cardinal): UInt64;
asm
end;
```

Explanation: In the normal `register` calling convention, the first two arguments (if cardinal-sized) are stored in EAX and EDX, respetively. A (cardinal-sized) result is stored in EAX. Now, a 64-bit result is stored in EAX (less significant bits, low address) and EDX (more significant bits, high address); hence we need to move `A` to EAX and `B` to EDX, but they are already there!

Comment: Thanks for considering my background, but as it turns out, I'm working in C and C++ right now. Your asm trick is clever. I'd name the variables `H` and `L` so that Code Completion would remind me what order they go in. My Delphi implementation would have been comparable to a C implementation: `Result := (UInt64(H) shl 32) or L`.

Comment: I had hoped for an answer a little more definitive than "I don't see one," but I probably set my sights too high, so this answer gets the prize. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer C-macros

```
#define MAKE_i64(hi, lo)    (  (LONGLONG(DWORD(hi) & 0xffffffff) << 32 ) | LONGLONG(DWORD(lo) & 0xffffffff)  )
```

Comment: I prefer functions, but this wasn't a question of personal preferences. It was a question of existence in the API. Is your answer *no*? Also, the bit masks contribute nothing in your macro.